# Overload 2 methods with same name and same parameter types

Tags: c#, asp.net

I got 2 methods with the same name and same parameter types. I want to overload those, but it does not work because I am getting this error:

```
"<Class-name> already defines a member called 'ChangeProfileInformation' 
 with the same parameter types"
```

I have something like this:

```
public void ChangeProfileInformation(User user)
{
   a
   b
}

public void ChangeProfileInformation(User user)
{
   a
   c
   d
}
```

Does anyone know why this doesn't work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How should the compiler be able to know which method it have to use? 
You can introduce 2 different names. in the second method you can call the first one

Comment: Are you trying to implement two interfaces? Then you can use _explicit interface implementation_.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Overloading means using same function name doing different things. For that Two function should have different signature otherwise compiler cant differentiate. You must have different signature.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that this should be possible, it's now clear for me.

Comment: If everything is the same apart from the parameter name does not count as a different signature?

Comment: @selectDistinct nope. Parameter name is not consider. It is parameter's type and number of parameters that is considered.

Answer (score 5):

The compiler wouldn't know which one to pick: how would it? You need to have a different name or different parameter types.

Alternatively why don't you use an optional flag to change the behaviour of the function instead?

Answer (score 1):

**Method Overloading** means Same method Name but with different method signature. `Method Signature signifies the Method Name with Input parameters.` You really can't achieve Method overloading with same method name with same parameter type.

You can better have a look into the detail concept of Method overloading from following sites:

http://www.dotnetperls.com/overload

http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Overloading.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you would want to do that, but if you really want to keep the same name have a dummy argument in one of the methods.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late but it is possible (posting example code as mentioned above), I had the exact same scenario today (constructor overloading, thus can't change name). Here is how I did it, small hack but it lets me have all my LINQ predicates that are related in the same place:

```
public BusinessStructureFilterSpecification(int responsibilityTypeId, bool dummy1 = true) : base(x => x.ResponsibleGroups.Any(x1 => x1.ResponsibilityTypeId == responsibilityTypeId))
{
    AddIncludes();
}

public BusinessStructureFilterSpecification(int userId, string dummy2 = "") : base(x => x.ResponsibleUsers.Any(x1 => x1.UserId == userId))
{
    AddIncludes();
}
```

Now the trick is to call them using parameter names like so:

```
if (responsibiltyTypeId.HasValue && !userId.HasValue)
    spec = new BusinessStructureFilterSpecification(responsibilityTypeId: responsibiltyTypeId.Value);

if (!responsibiltyTypeId.HasValue && userId.HasValue)
    spec = new BusinessStructureFilterSpecification(userId: userId.Value);
```